# directive in angularjs does not show?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am playing around with a directive in an angular js application. This is a fragment of my directive:

```
(function() {
    var gMaps = function($timeout, $q, GeoCoder, mockdataService) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div class="gmaps"></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

..
```

In my index.html I have the directive:

```
 <gMaps center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom"></gMaps>
```

When I debug in the console it does not even hit the gmaps.js file? There are no visible errors in the console. What could be wrong?
this is a url for the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/fEsaE9XpgmKFqO194X4G?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
<gMaps center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom"></gMaps>
```

To:

```
<g-maps center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom"></g-maps>
```

[EDITED PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/ATPhByDkuIwtBMcyCjtB?p=preview)